# How to limit the retry count of ImagePullBackOff when the docker is not accessible?

Tags: kubernetes

In my kubernetes job, I wrote a wrong docker name, and I find that my job keeps in a state of `ImagePullBackOff`. I want the job release resources, and stop pulling docker image since the image name is wrong. I noticed that there is a imagePullPolicy configuration, but seems does not meet my request. I want the job always pull docker images, but has a retry count limit for pulling. Does kubernetes support this action?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `backoffLimit` and `activeDeadlineSeconds` as generic controller to quit the job after specified number of failures.

Example

```
 apiVersion: batch/v1
 kind: Job
 metadata:
   name: myjob
   namespace: default
 spec:
   backoffLimit: 5
   activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
   template:
     metadata:
       name: myjob
     spec:
       containers:
       - name: nginx
         image: wrong_image_name
       restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

> By setting the `activeDeadlineSeconds` field of the Job to a number of seconds. The `activeDeadlineSeconds` applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created.
>
> Once a Job reaches `activeDeadlineSeconds`, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: `Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded`

Comment: The problem with using `activeDeadlineSeconds` is that the job gets stopped either way after 100 seconds. Also if it is successfully running.